# Showing graph sequentially not just the last one

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

When I do the following using Pandas on IPython, it only shows the last picture I drawn, is there a way I can let them show sequentially on IPython?

```
def drawBar(colName):
    df1=df[colName].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=colName)

drawBar("myBiscuit")
drawBar("myBedRoom")
...(many more drawBar)
```

Comment: Do you want a pause before showing the next one, or an interactive mode - i.e. wait for the previous one to be closed?

Comment: @doctorlove Just show all at once

Comment: Lots of windows or lots of subplots?

Comment: @doctorlove lots of plots or subplots

Comment: I don't think I can help without more info, but two things. First the `plot` command has a `suplot parameter which you can use to make subplots. Second if `matplotlib.is_interactive()` reports False, the graphs should all show (one for each plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plotting graphs in the notebook, you'd use the IPython magic `%matplotlib inline`.

#### (a) Plotting each individual graph one after the other:

You would need to call `plt.show()` for each graph. This will return a long list of plots in your IPython.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

colNames = "ABCDEFGHI"
x = np.random.randint(0,5, size=(10, 9))

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=[letter for letter in colNames])

 
def drawBar(colName):
    df1=df[colName].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=colName)

for i in range(9):
    drawBar(colNames[i])
    plt.show()
```

[image]

#### (b) Using subplots.

Creating several subplots can be done with `plt.subplots()`. Then using the `ax` keyword argument to the pandas plotting function, creates the graph on the specified axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

colNames = "ABCDEFGHI"
x = np.random.randint(0,5, size=(10, 9))

df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=[letter for letter in colNames])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3)
 
def drawBar(colName, ax):
    df1=df[colName].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title=colName, ax=ax)

for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    drawBar(colNames[i], ax)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]